# Managing Fragment to Fragment Navigation

Tags: android, user-interface, navigation

Recently, I began working on an app that has one main activity and several child fragments that are swapped in and out of a single container.

My question is simple: is it recommended to let each Fragment switch to the next fragment in the UI flow by calling `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replaceFragment()...`, or should each Fragment define an interface that the main activity implements and let the main activity handle the app's navigation?

**Pros of Activity Managing the Fragments**

- More maintainable in the sense that the fragments aren't dependent on a single particular activity and can be swapped into and out of arbitrary layouts.
- UI navigation code is centralized in a single class.

**Cons of Activity Managing the Fragments**

- Activity will have to implement tons of interfaces, cluttering up the code. There has to be a better way than implementing 15 interfaces that all indicate that the fragment is finished and ready to move onto the next stage of the UI.
- If someone else reads the code, the UI navigation is not as intuitive. Consider an example with three fragments called A, B, and C, and assume that fragment A moves to B on some action and B moves to C on some action. The direction of this flow is not readily apparent if each fragment has to go through an intermediary interface in order to move to the next fragment.

One solution I've come up with is to have a single interface that contains a callback for each fragment, eliminating the need for a ton of individual interfaces. I still feel like there's a better way of doing this, though.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting question and I don't think there is a perfect answer, it depends on a lot of things. But from my experience:

I try to mainly use the activity as a "controller", while the fragments represent the "views". So it's better to let the activity handle the navigation. This helps keeps things modular and makes life easier when for example you want to create a tablet version (that combines a few fragments together on a single page), or change the flow of your app.

But, as you say in your "cons" section, this leads to a lot of code in the Activity. If you have just one Activity in your app with 15 fragments, the Activity code is not going to be very readable.

So - try to group your fragments and have an Activity for each group. For example, you might have a couple of screens to "view user profile" and "edit user profile" - each of these could be a fragment within the UserActivity. Then you might have an Activity for say StoreDetailsFragment and StoreMapFragment, and another Activity for a purchase flow.

Basically, having minimal code in Activity classes is A Good Thing in my book - if some Activities contain just one fragment, I'm fine with that.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a project which can make Fragment to Fragment Navigation easy:

https://github.com/fengdai/FragmentMaster

Answer (score 0):

I created library in Kotlin for fragment navigation. There is an ability to use stack or pager or both. Usage is pretty easy. Tested and used in production code. Documentation is not ready yet but you can run sample project on your device and look into code.

https://github.com/zyvpeople/FragmentNavigation